# Scale svg images in ImageView

Tags: android

I have imageViews bound to svg files using [android-svg](https://github.com/pents90/svg-android) lib, which works. Unfortunately, there is an inconsistency in the sizes of the rendered svg images; some fit perfectly, some are super small. I have tried changing various ImageView attributes, but nothing that I have tried fixes the problem.

Is there an attribute that needs to be set that I am missing?

Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.testImage);

    SVG homeSvg = SVGParser.getSVGFromString(getResources().getString(R.string.svg));
    imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(homeSvg.createPictureDrawable());

    return v;
}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/testImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: The logo can faintly be seen in the top left corner]

Comment: Try to edit all your svg files, to normalize their initial scale

Comment: Unfortunately, all the svg data is being fetched from an api. I will try to edit the dimensions if I can't find any other way.

Answer (score 2):

i am not aware of svg images but attribute you are using

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

will work on bitmap where i also got this issue when i setting image drawable so i converted drwable to bitmap and set imagebitmap  to imageview then it worked also checkwith setImageDrawable()